# Rest Template release Connection from Pool

Tags: spring, connection-pooling, resttemplate

I have rest template config similar to the following.  I am trying to release a connection from the pool if I get a status code that does not equal 2XX (long story but need this code).  Is here a way I can get the connection Manager and release a specific connection?

```
@Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        connectionManager.setMaxTotal(100);
        connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20);

    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig
        .custom()
        .setConnectionRequestTimeout(5000) // timeout to get connection from pool
        .setSocketTimeout(5000) // standard connection timeout
        .setConnectTimeout(5000) // standard connection timeout
        .build();

    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                                             .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
                                             .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build();

    ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);


    return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
}
```

Looking for a way to accomplish something similar to the following

```
if(!httpStatusCode.substr(1).equals("2")) {
  restTemplate.getConnectionPool().relase().thisConnection();
}
enter code here
```

Comment: Looking like I might be able to use a HTTP Request Interceptor?

Comment: At this point Im leaning towards extending PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager and overriding releaseConnection.... No just trying to figure out how to get the http status code for the last useage of that connection into the releaseConnection method.